# Best way to chain multiple NSUrlConnection in iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsurlconnection

I couldn't find a reasonable answer so i'll ask for this specific case.

I must perform a http call (setting a specific header as a token value) and parse the returned json. The json can both return a "operation completed" message or a "token expired" message.

In case of token expired i must execute another http call which will provide me the refreshed token, set the token as header and re-execute the original http call.

I decided to adopt this solution: from the main thread, i'm gonna create another thread using

```
...
dispatch_async(feedQueue
...
```

and in this thread i'm gonna performing the above descripted calls as **synchronous** calls using

```
...
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
...
```

and only at the end of the flow i call the main thread passing results to a block.

This way code is simple, easy to read, it has a linear flow, it is completely scoped inside a unique thread, and i don't mess with delegates and different "finite-states" to manage calls chain.

But i'm not sure if this is the best approach for my specific use-case as i've read similar questions where people suggest to adopt **asynchronous** calls, using both finite-states or NSOperation instances, but it seems to me that both these approaches based on asynchronous calls, are not the best solutions for a http calls chain.

What is the best approach? How can i correctly implement a chain of http call?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set this up would be to use asynchronous calls for NSURLConnection. In the connectionDidFinishLoading you will intercept the connection that just finished and launch the next chained http connection.

Setup a private variable called _connection1;

So basically, you will do something like this

```
NSURLRequest * request1 = ...

_connection1 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];


In the 
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

if([connection isEqual:_connection1]){
NSURLRequest *request2 = ...
_connection2 = [NSURLConnection...]


}

if([connection isEqual:_connection2]){
NSURLRequest *request3 = ...
_connection2 = [NSURLConnection...request3 ]


// And so on ....

}
```

}

Comment: Ok, but delegate's method are called on starting thread (usually main thread) so this means that if i had a 10 calls chain, i would interrupt 10 times the main thread; also i should start a new thread to process web call result if the response processing is time-consuming. And last i have to declare the connection variables and store the callback block passed to my load method. My approach lives entirely in one parallel thread.

Comment: I think the delegate methods might not necessarily be called on the main thread - it depends on the context of your delegate. This is the way I use and works for me. Curious to see if someone has a better method here.

Comment: Yes, it is not necessary the main thread, but most of the time it will be, otherwise you have to create another thread just to avoid main thread blocking and so the asynchronous approach becomes too messy and useless. Curious to see other solutions too!